# How do I add custom fields to Gravity Forms?

Tags: plugin-gravity-forms

I'm trying to create a custom check box with a text field after it like:

[  ] option 1
[  ] option 2
[  ] option 3
[  ] other  ***_*__**

Answer (score 1):

You can create a separate conditional text field.

1. Create a multiple choice question with your three options plus your "other" selection. Enable the value fields and assign a value of "0" or "-1" to "other."
2. Add a text box next and then go to the "Advanced" tab and check "Enable conditional logic." Configure the appropriate selection based on the multiple choice question. For example, "My Option List" "is" "fourth choice".